# Null returns in a simple Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I'm currently working on my Programming Fundamentals w/ Python final project which is a collection of small games. I'm trying to make the game "High Card", where 2 random numbers between 1 & 13(the face values of a 52 card deck) are generated, then compared for the higher number and a winner is displayed.

We are required to have seperate files for the Class and Program code. This is what my Class looks like.

```
import random

class card:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.card_value = value

    def deal(self):
        numb = random.randrange(1, 13)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.card_value = value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.card_value

    def find_face_value(self, numb):
        #face = 'test'
        print(numb)
        if numb == 1:
            print("numb == 1")
            return 'Ace'
        elif numb == 2:
            return 'two'
    ##        elif numb == 3:
    ##            face = 'three'
    ##        elif numb == 4:
    ##            face = 'four'
    ##        elif numb == 5:
    ##            face = 'five'
    ##        elif numb == 6:
    ##            face = 'six'
    ##        elif numb == 7:
    ##            face = 'seven'
    ##        elif numb == 8:
    ##            face = 'eight'
    ##        elif numb == 9:
    ##            face = 'nine'
    ##        elif numb == 10:
    ##            face = 'ten'
    ##        elif numb == 11:
    ##            face = 'jack'
    ##        elif numb == 12:
    ##            face = 'queen'
    ##        elif numb == 13:
    ##            face = 'king'
        #return face

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Numeric Value: ' + str(self.card_value)
```

I've commented out those (if numb == ...) statements b/c I am testing to see if I can get one correct return.
And Here is my Program code for the game.

```
def high_card():
    #player1_card = cardClass.card(random.randrange(1, 13))
    player1_card = cardClass.card(1)
    player2_card = cardClass.card(2)
    card1 = player1_card.find_face_value(player1_card)
    #player2_card = cardClass.card(random.randrange(1, 13))
    card2 = player2_card.find_face_value(player2_card)
    print('Player 1 got', card1, player1_card, '\nPlayer 2 got', card2, player2_card)
```

And this is the output I recieve when I run the high_card() function.

```
>>> high_card()
Numeric Value: 1
Numeric Value: 2
Player 1 got None Numeric Value: 1 
Player 2 got None Numeric Value: 2
```

My problem is in the last 2 lines of the output. It should say "Player 1 got Ace Numeric Value: 1" and "Player 2 got two Numeric Value: 2". I need the find_face_value function in my class to return a string of the "face" of a card. Instead, Python is printing "None", implying that I did not return anything inside the find_face_value function. I'm stumped on what to do to get this working and would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
card1 = player1_card.find_face_value(player1_card)
```

In the statement above, `numb` is neither 1 nor 2. `numb` is a card class (you assigned numb=player1_card). So those if statements inside `find_face_value` are both false, thus return values are skipped. Python returns `None` by default. You have to check `self.card_value` inside if statements, instead of checking `numb`.

```
def find_face_value(self):
    if self.card_value == 1:
        print("card value is 1")
        return 'Ace'
    elif self.card_value == 2:
        return 'two'


card1 = player1_card.find_face_value()
print(card1)
```

the statement above should print 'Ace'.